# Error: Cannot read property 'UIAppFonts' of null

Tags: reactjs, react-native

When running `react-native link` it gives this error,

[image: the error]

It says,

`rnpm-install ERR! It seems something went wrong while linking. Error: Cannot read property 'UIAppFonts' of null`

Comment: Did you try to add custom font for your IOS app?

Comment: @DinithMinura actually machan I was developing an android app, but error comes in linking ios native components. I solved the error in a random method, may not be the best solution.

Comment: OK @Dinuka rnpm command links modules for both android and ios, If you really focusing only for android app,  I thinks its good to go with manually installation for android, anyway for the IOS you have to edit Info.plist and add a property called Fonts provided by application (or UIAppFonts if Xcode won't autocomplete/not using Xcode) and add font file names which you added to Xcode project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had same issue not quite long, running `react-native links` will give you error.
If you are using yarn simply run:

1. `yarn remove react-native`
2. `yarn add react-native`
3. Then run `react-native link`

This fixed it for me.

Comment: Didn't fix the problem for me

Answer (score 3):

I had this exact same problem.  I had accidentally deleted by `Info.plist` file in my ios directory.  Restoring it, fixed my issue.

Comment: Won't fix the problem for me

Comment: Didn't fix the problem for me

Answer (score 3):

I had this problem and in my case it was because I had renamed the project but forgotten to update newname in a few folders and files.

Answer (score 1):

In case anyone runs across this, this is how I fixed the react-native linking issue w/ UIAppFonts:

```
# Regenerates ios files
react-native upgrade

# Works now
react-native link
```

Basically, it's pretty similar to the answer that Matt posts above, except I didn't know how to restore it.

Comment: Didn't fix the problem for me